# unexpected '$fname' (T_VARIABLE)?

Tags: php, mysql

I am not able to figure out what kind of error is this. I'm doing db input in MySQL via PHP in XAMPP server.

```
$data = 'UPDATE `personnel` SET fname='$fname', mname='$mname', lname='$lname' WHERE        `SERV_NO` = "'.$Key.'"';
```

Error is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$fname' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\update_per.php on line 11

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting in the question. You're using `'` both to delimit your string, as well as inside your SQL. Try using `"` at the start and end of your string, instead of `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Surround your $data with "" instead of ''

```
$data = "UPDATE `personnel` SET fname='$fname', mname='$mname', lname='$lname' WHERE        `SERV_NO` = '$Key'";
```

Comment: awesome help.... i was also thinking same, just some few minutes after posting this!!thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to vote the answer you found useful.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to use the double quotes. Otherwise you have to concat the string.

```
$data = "UPDATE `personnel` SET fname='$fname',....
```

or

```
$data = 'UPDATE `personnel` SET fname="'.$fname.'",....
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatination was not proper , it should be like this

```
 $data = "UPDATE `personnel` SET fname='$fname', mname='$mname', lname='$lname' WHERE  `SERV_NO` = '$Key'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do:

```
$data = "UPDATE `personnel` SET fname='$fname', mname='$mname', lname='$lname' WHERE `SERV_NO` = '$Key'";
```

What you're doing (or trying to do) is variable interpolation - where, in PHP, defined variables are evaluated within double-quoted strings. This isn't possible with single-quoted strings.

Alternatively, you can concatenate with single-quoted strings... your choice.